# Using external diff in a custom action in SourceTree

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, examdiff

I have many files which SourceTree claims to have been altered, but when looking in comparison view it shows everything having been replaced with exactly the same thing. I set up SourceTree to use ExamDiff as the External Diff from the context menu and ExamDiff claims they are identical.

To speed things up with discarding identical files I wanted to set up a custom action that used ExamDiff and if it returns 0 (identical) the changes would be discarded.

However, when setting up External Diff I have access to $REMOTE and $LOCAL so that the changes can be differentiated. I don't seem to have access to those when setting up a Custom Action, so I'm at a loss for how to do this.

I'm using SourceTree with Git, btw.

Comment: I bet this is a line ending issue.

Comment: That's what I think too, but I would still like to create this custom action to solve these issues with a single click in the future.

Comment: Doesn't "Ignore whitespace" work for you?

Comment: Maybe. Solving the reason for my problem doesn't actually solve what I'm asking about.